# Find multiplicity of a root of polynomials in 2 variables

Tags: polynomials

I have a bunch of integer polynomials in 2 variables which vanish at the point `{1,1}` and would like a simple way to find the multiplicity of this particular root for each of the polynomials. I'm confident I could check a ton of partial derivatives and calculate it that way but this seems like the kind of thing that would have a much nicer solution.

Comment: Can you define multiplicity in the 2-variable case? What is the multiplicity of `(x-1)^2 (y-1)^3 (x+y)`?

Comment: By multiplicity, I mean the order of vanishing. The polynomial you gave would have a multiplicity of 5. You factored it into pieces with multiplicities 2,3,0 respectively.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how about `x y - 1` then?

Comment: xy-1 has multiplicity 1. For simple polynomials it is easy to figure out by hand. Doesn't vanish at {1,1} means multiplicity 0, does vanish means at least 1, all nth degree or less partial derivatives vanish means at least multiplicity n+1.

Comment: The rough idea is to count the number of solutions at (1,1) when you intersect with a random linear form through that point. If you post a specific example it would help considerably (that is to say, I'd be happy to show more detail).

Comment: Its trivial to generate examples of polynomials that vanish at {1,1}, how about this one: `x^3 y^2 - 3 x*y + y + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, it's trivial to generate examples. Which is no excuse for expecting people reading the thread to do something that should have been done in the original post.]

Start with our example.

```
poly = x^3*y^2 - 3*x*y + y + 1;
```

The multiplicity at `{1,1}` is the multiplicty of solution set there when we intersect with a generic hyperplane through that point. For practical purposes generic can be replaced with random.

We are not interested in other zeros that may lie on the curve and hyperplane. We can localize (remove zeros other than the one of interest) using a larger power of `(x-1)` and `(y-1)`. How large must it be? Notice that multiplicity cannot exceed total degree so degree 4 suffices in this case.

```
randpoly11 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 2].{x - 1, y - 1};
gb = GroebnerBasis[{poly, randpoly11, (x - 1)^4, (y - 1)^4}, {x, y}];
Factor[gb]

(* Out[132]= {(-1 + y)^2, -1 + x} *)
```

So the multiplicity of the zero at `{1,1}` is 2*1 = 2.